# How to get grep -o to also output filename

Tags: grep

I have a number of large files (hundreds of Mb) with no line breaks. I need to search for a string in those files, plus a few surrounding characters, which I am doing with

```
grep -o '...target_string...'`
```

How can I also get grep to output the filenames? `grep -Ho ...` doesn't seem to work as I would hope.

Comment: `-Ho` flag is supported in both `GNU grep` and `FreeBSD` version. What is not working when using `-Ho`?

Comment: FreeBSD. But it's my fault - I was output on the first matching line but not subsequent ones, And I didn't spot it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - my fault, I'm being dense. It *does* work, but only outputs the filename on the first output line. If there are multiple matches within a file, the filename is only output once.